# Exposing ingress to host windows machine when running minikube in vagrant virtualbox (ubuntu VM) with docker driver

Tags: kubernetes, vagrant, virtualbox, minikube, forgerock

I am running a vagrant box using virtual box (running headless ubuntu 18.04) on windows 10 host machine.
Inside the virtual box, I have minikube set up using docker as the vm-driver

*minikube start --memory=6144 --cpus=2 --disk-size=40g --vm-driver=docker --bootstrapper kubeadm --kubernetes-version=1.17.4*

My application is exposed via an ingress to the ubuntu machine running inside virtual box and I am able to access the application via wget/cURL
[image]

On running minikube IP it gave me the IP of the docker container in which minikube runs
[image]

Some additional configuration info -
[image]
[image]

Vagrant file -

[image]

I would like to access the application from my windows machine's browser , any idea how to achieve that ? vagrant port forwarding doesn't seem to help.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use a setup like this(using vagrant etc.). You can just use `--vm-driver=none` and let the kubernetes run in your ubuntu box directly, this way you can leverage port-forwarding. You probably also can do it your way but I've never tried so I wouldn't know, but I know that `none` works. You can follow this [guide](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/drivers/none/).

There are different options like running minikube on windows directly. Which is perfectly fine as well.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. `--vm-driver=none` doesn't support ingress add ons , so that's unfortunately not an option for me. I want to set this up in a VM (vagrant or not vagrant). The issue is that I am not able to access the application outside of VM on the host machine.

Comment: I have also tried using the `--vm-driver=vrtualbox` but that also fails during creation of minikube VM .., with docker as the vm driver I was able to set up the application but can't access it outside of the VM.

Comment: You don't need ingress addon. Just install nginx ingress as helm chart, and make it use NodePort. Access from local machine by the NodePort. If you are beginner and don't want to do it, then I can't really help you sorry.

Comment: I understand the alternate approaches suggested by you but that's not what my question is about. I am setting up an packaged application (forgerock , an IAM product), so don't really have much option to do things on my own .... https://backstage.forgerock.com/docs/forgeops/6.5/devops-guide-minikube/#chap-devops-implementation-env